# Query that returns results that are at least a week apart

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a google sheets spreadsheet that has lots of user data, timestamped. This data is entered into the google sheet by administration AND end users via a google form, so the data points don't come in at regular intervals.  I want to be able to query against this datapool, but limit the results shown based a defined amount of time between result.  [image: Data-Sample-1]

So say I wanted to query for Bob, I would get 3 results. Is it possible to query this data in a way that it would see the 11\11 result, but disregard the 11\12 result becuase it's within a week of the previous result? Really I'd like to be able to do this for any timeframe.

Comment: Possible. You would sort your data, find the time difference between adjacent timestamps and then pass it to query, where the diff >1wk. Share your sheet.

Comment: Trying to think this through - If you had 3 timestamps each four days apart, presumably you would want to keep the first and third, because they are more than a week apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's easy enough to do as an ordinary formula that you can pull down like this, but I don't see a way of doing it as a query or array formula:

```
=iferror(if(istext(F1),index(A$2:A,match(true,(B$2:B=$F$1),0)),index(A$2:A,match(1,(B$2:B=$F$1)*((A$2:A-F1)>=7),0))))
```

where the person's name is in F1.

[image]

This is a fairly rough outline of an answer, I haven't taken account of any time part of the timestamps. The last two dates are only separated by 6 days, but the formula includes the third to last and the last one as mentioned in my comment because they are separated by 7 days.